# AttributeError: can't set attribute error occurred when init subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote below code with python 3.6.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self._p1
    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p1):
        self._p1 = p1

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return self._p2
    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, p2):
        self._p2 = p2

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
        super(B, self).__init__(p1, p2)
        self.p3 = p3

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self._p1 if self.p3 is None else self._p1+1

    @property
    def p3(self):
        return self._p3
    @p3.setter
    def p3(self, p3):
        self._p3 = p3

b1 = B(1,2,3)
```

When create instance with class B `'AttributeError: can't set attribute'` occurred. How do I fix it?

Comment: Seems to me like your `self.p1 = p1` should be `self._p1 = p1`

Comment: Who has marked this question for closing? The problem is reproducible and the code is complete in itself

Comment: @ycx No, that's not a problem (although breaking the abstraction for efficiency is probably OK within `A`'s own methods.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define @p1.setter also for class B

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self._p1
    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p1):
        self._p1 = p1

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return self._p2
    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, p2):
        self._p2 = p2

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
        super(B, self).__init__(p1, p2)
        self.p3 = p3

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self._p1 if self.p3 is None else self._p1+1

    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p1):
        self._p1 = p1

    @property
    def p3(self):
        return self._p3
    @p3.setter
    def p3(self, p3):
        self._p3 = p3

b1 = B(1, 2, 3)
b2 = B(1, 2, None)

print(b1.p1)
print(b2.p1)
```

output

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in `B`, you've overriden the entire property `p1`, not just the getter of `A`'s property by the same name. You need to provide the setter explicitly.

```
class B(A):
    ...

    # Not sure if there is a better method than
    # simply copying this from A. (At least,
    # not without creating your own custom property
    # descriptor that supports inheritance.)
    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, x):
        self._p1 = x
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in class B, you only have the property for `p1`, without a setter. That makes `p1` a read-only property. In class A, at the line:

```
    self.p1 = p1
```

you will get the `AttributeError` because you are trying to overwrite a read-only property. The fix is to add a setter for class B:

```
@p1.setter
def p1(self, p1):
    print('Setting B.p1 = {}'.format(p1))
    self._p1 = p1
```

With this addition, re-run your code and you will notice the print output. Once happy, you can remove that print line.